# Diagnostics for PLSR?

Tags: regression, pca, multivariate-analysis, partial-least-squares

I am trying to apply sPLS2 type pf regression my matrix y has a set of clinical variables and matrix X has some gene data. I am using mixOmics package in R.

My question is how to decide that my model has a good fit. The R2 are very low for each Y predicted (no more that 0.2) in any case. If only R2 is a measure of fit, what else can I try alternatively?

Comment: What did you read? What did you try?

Comment: I checked the components based on RMSEP (2 components),10 fold cross validation.But the R2 are really low ,what is the goodness of fit?

Comment: What does literature about PLS tell you about checking goodness of fit? What does the literature in your field tell you about $R^2$ as you typically observe it for your type of data? Is goodness of fit really the characteristic you are interested in? why? Please make your homework before asking questions, and when asking, give us information about your problem. As it is, the question as well as your comment show a distinct lack in understanding what you are doing - including that you do either do not know what information is crucial, or do not care to give it.

Comment: And BTW: the $\mathrm{RMSE}$ you obtain by cross validation is usually denoted $\mathrm{RMSE_{CV}}$ as opposed to $\mathrm{RMSE_P}$ which refers to prediction of truly independent cases.

Comment: Thank you .I've found good material for understanding the content correctly.    [http://www.libpls.net/publication/PLS_basic_2001.pdf]